# Vuejs directive binding a model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-select2

I'm using a Vuejs 1.0 directive to turn a select field (single and multiple) into a Select2 jQuery plugin field.

```
Vue.directive('select2', {
    twoWay: true,
    priority: 1000,

    params: ['max-items'],

    bind: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.params);

        $(this.el)
            .select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: self.params.maxItems,
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                closeOnSelect: true
            })
            .on('change', function () {
                var i, len, option, ref, values;
                if (self.el.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
                    values = [];
                    ref = self.el.selectedOptions;
                    for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                        option = ref[i];
                        values.push(option.value);
                    }
                    return self.set(values);
                } else {
                    return self.set(self.el.value);
                }
            })
    },
    update: function (value, oldValue) {
        $(this.el).val(value).trigger('change')
    },
    unbind: function () {
        $(this.el).off().select2('destroy')
    }
});
```

This all works fine. I'm also trying to bind a model to the value of the field but can't seem to get it to bind properly.

```
<select class="form-control" name="genre" v-model="upload.genre" v-select2="">
<option value="50">Abstract</option>
<option value="159">Acapella</option>
<option value="80">Acid</option>
...
</select>
```

The `upload.genre` property does not update automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components) is actually syntactic sugar on passing a prop and on change event setting the value, so following:

```
<input v-model="something">
```

is equivalent of

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

You have to also make similar changes, You can see this type code in the [select2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) example provided by vue team.

```
  .on('change', function () {
    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
  })
```

### With Vue 1.0

As you are using vue 1.0, there is a [two-way](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#twoWay) options for directives which helps to write data back to the Vue instance, you need to pass in twoWay: true. This option allows the use of this.set(value) inside the directive:

```
Vue.directive('select2', {
  twoWay: true,
  bind: function () {
    this.handler = function () {
      // set data back to the vm.
      // If the directive is bound as v-select2="upload.genre",
      // this will attempt to set `vm.upload.genre` with the
      // given value.
      this.set(this.el.value)
    }.bind(this)
    this.el.addEventListener('input', this.handler)
  },
  unbind: function () {
    this.el.removeEventListener('input', this.handler)
  }
})
```

and in HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="genre" v-select2="upload.genre">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I neglected to mention that I'm using Vuejs 1.0 and I'm also using a directive not a component. Can it still be done?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you could kindly help me once again. I've used your code and it works great when a model is provided, but it doesn't work if no model is provided and the select list already has a selected item. It always uses the models value to set the select2 list value - here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4r36a1s1/ - appreciate the help.

Comment: @Wasim You have to give the initial value in `update` inside your directive, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r36a1s1/3/), I have hardcode this as of now, it can be passed as well.